# Checking existing user in model and inform him about it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, architecture

My django project has app which called 'Projects' with model. Model has field 'manager_of_the_project' where admin can choice existing user or users of web site. My question is how to show to these users in there personal page that they were selected by admin as the manager of the project? I just need ideas how to realise it. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Relationships are covered in great detail in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use reverse relations, e.g.
in your models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    manager_of_the_project = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE, related_name='projects')
```

Then from your user model you can check if the user is a manager of any projects like this:

```
user.projects
```